# throw exception from SchedulerExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, junit-jupiter

Is there anyway to throw/propagate the exception out from SchedulerExecutorService?

I can wrap my runnable and have errorHandler in it but this wont stop my application .

Is there anyway i can access the main thread from singleton but how do force main thread to throw exception

```
@Test
    public void executorTest()throws Exception{
        Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try{
                Integer.parseInt("error");
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.err.println("catch error");
                //mainThread.interrupt(); //i want to fail the test , but need a better way
                throw new RuntimeException(e); //this will not affect main thread
            }
        },0,100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("shout not see this statement");
    }
```

Comment: "and have errorHandler in it but this wont stop my application " surely that depends on how you implement the error handler.

Answer (score 1):

Unit test should test a small piece of logic. If the goal is to test the parsing functionality, the recommended approach is extract the logic to a new method(parse()) and call the parse() method from scheduler run. The junit can call the parse() and test the behaviour..

Rather if the intention is to verify the scheduling part too, then you  need a communication model between scheduler thread and main thread. Have two different error handler implementations (production, unit test), and inject the error handler as a dependency.